# How to wrap jQuery function in a div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering how I can surround a each function with a div. Below is a function that will generate for each playlist the title and tracks of Soundcloud API. 
What I want is surrounding each "album" / "playlist" with a `div` element, like so:

```
<div id="album-one">
    <h2></h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Track name</li>
        <li>Track name</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="album-two">
    <h2></h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Track name</li>
        <li>Track name</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my current code:

```
$(playlists).each(function (index, playlist) {

    $('.list-of-links').append($('<li></li>').html('<a href="#">' + playlist.title + '</a>'));
    $('#playlist').append($('<h2></h2>').html(playlist.title));

    var count = 0;

    // Get each track of the playlist
    $(playlist.tracks).each(function (index, track) {
        index = index + 1;
        $('#playlist').append($('<li data-id="' + track.id + '"></li>').html('<a href="#" class="play">Play</a> <a href="#" class="pause">Pause</a>' + (index++) + ' / ' + track.title + '  ' + track.playback_count));
        $("#cover").append('<div><img src="' + track.artwork_url.replace('-large', '-t500x500') + '"></div>');

    });

});
```

My HTML markup:

```
<main class="col-md-9">
    <ul class="list-of-links">
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Bleep</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Machine</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cinematographic</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Micro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Songs that might be</a></li>
</ul><!-- End ul.list-of-links -->

<section class="row albums">
    <figure id="cover" class="col-md-7"></figure>

    <div id="playlist" class="col-md-5">
    </div><!-- End div#playlist .col-md-5 -->

    </section><!-- End section.albums -->      

    <footer id="footer" class="alignRight">
                    <img src="images/soundcloud.png" alt="SoundCloud Credits">
    </footer><!-- End footer#footer .alignRight -->
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more, unsure what you are asking here.

Comment: try $( playlists).wrap( "<div id='album' + count></div>" );

Comment: It will not wrap each playlist inside the div. There will be show only one album now..

Comment: Could you possibly provide a fiddle showing your current situation? http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: Than the API doesn't work so there will not generate all albums..

Comment: just provide the html

Comment: See above for my HTML markup @Sushil

Comment: I think your approach is flawed. You should be inserting content, not wrapping JavaScript with HTML.